# Component Factory Krypton Toolkit not working on Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, krypton-toolkit

Hi there I have installed the krypton toolkit which makes your program look a lot more disgner friendly.
Heres my problem.
I can't use the toolkit i try looking through all of the options but no answer and i look on the internet no answer how can i use the toolkit on vs 2012 because i know it used to work on vs 2010

Answer (score 9):

The Krypton Toolkit works fine in Visual Studio 2012.

You might have to manually add the controls to your toolbox in order to use them in the way you are accustomed to.

1. Show the toolbox by clicking on the 'VIEW' menu, and then the 'Toolbox' menu item.
2. Right-click on the toolbox, and click 'Choose items'.
3. Click the 'Browse' button, and navigate to the Krypton directory. This is usually `C:\Program Files\Component Factory\Krypton Toolkit x.y.z\Bin\` where x.y.z is your installed Krypton version. It will be in `Program Files (x86)` if you are running 64-bit windows.
4. Select the `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll` file (and, optionally, the other Krypton files: `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.dll`, `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Workspace.dll`, `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Docking.dll`, and `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Ribbon.dll`).
5. Click the 'Open' button.

Your toolbox will now be populated with the Krypton controls, and you can use them just as you did with the previous Visual Studio versions.

Answer (score -1):

That's got it. Thanks.
Once OPEN you'll notice them under the name Krypton .... in the "All Windows Forms" toolbox listing.
You also need to browse for it in the menu>Project >> Add Reference and then navigate to the same dll at C:\Program Files\Component Factory\Krypton Toolkit 4.4.0\Bin\ (current version at Mar 2013).
Now you'll be able to declare "using ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit;"
Around 37 controls should appear now in the design screen.